# Android acharengine - the graph disappears as soon as the data points are not in the visible area?

Tags: android, opengl-es, graph, rendering, achartengine

I've made normal line chart using achartengine which can pan,zoom.etc.

Initially the chart was disappearing on pan.

I was getting the **OpenGl rendered warning** -*path too large to be rendered into a texture*.

and I turned Hardware acceleration to false and that solved the problem.

Now when I zoom the graph and if the data points go beyond the visible area the graph kind of disappears and it sets the axis to 0000-0-0000.

Please refer to the attached screenshots.

when the points are in the visible region:-

[image: When the points are in the visible region]

As I zoom the points go beyond the visible region:-

[image: As I zoom the points go beyond the visible region]

Is this the problem of the Library.
If yes,thn anyone has any solution for this?

Edited:----

Here is some code:

```
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(8);
if (mChartView == null) {
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        leftDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.left_date);
        rightDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right_date);

        layout.setEnabled(true);
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset,
                mRenderer);
        // enable the chart click events
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);
        String seriesTitle = "Series " + (mDataset.getSeriesCount() + 1);
        // create a new series of data
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries(seriesTitle);
        mDataset.addSeries(series);
        mCurrentSeries = series;
        // create a new renderer for the new series
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        renderer.setPointStrokeWidth(5);
        renderer.setShowLegendItem(false);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);
        renderer.setFillBelowLine(true);
        renderer.setFillBelowLineColor(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.graph_green));
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);
        renderer.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(20);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        // set some renderer properties

        mCurrentRenderer = renderer;
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        // mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        // mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        // mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
        mRenderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 0);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(8f);
        mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.GRAY);
        mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        try {
            FetchWeight fetchWeight = FetchWeightCacheManager
                    .getObject(Controller.getAppBackgroundContext());
            if (fetchWeight.getData().size() != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < fetchWeight.getData().size(); i++) {
                    kilo = (long) fetchWeight.getData().get(i).getKilos();
                    weight_date = (long) fetchWeight.getData().get(i)
                            .getTimestamp();
                    if (count == 0) {
                        default_start_date = weight_date - 100000;
                        System.out.println("default start date = "
                                + default_start_date);
                        mCurrentSeries.add(default_start_date, kilo);
                        weights.add(kilo);
                        dates.add(default_start_date);
                        count++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("time:" + weight_date);
                    System.out.println("kilo:" + kilo);
                    mCurrentSeries.add(weight_date, kilo);
                    weights.add(kilo);
                    dates.add(weight_date);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No weights to fetch :" + e);
        }
        double minx = mRenderer.getXAxisMin();
        double maxx = mRenderer.getXAxisMax();
        System.out.println("min x = " + minx);
        System.out.println("max x = " + maxx);
        mRenderer.setRange(new double[] { default_start_date,
                weight_date + 1000000, kilo - 20, kilo + 20 });
        mY.setText("");
        // repaint the chart such as the newly added point to be visible
        mChartView.repaint();
```

Here is the pan listener:

```
            mChartView.addPanListener(new PanListener() {

            private double timestampdouble;
            private Integer image_index;
            private int mid_value;
            private Double max_double;
            private Double min_double;

            public void panApplied() {
                // customListAdapter.setGraphTouched(true);

                ArrayList<Long> insideweights = new ArrayList<Long>();
                double minx = mRenderer.getXAxisMin();
                double maxx = mRenderer.getXAxisMax();
                long minx_default = (long) minx;
                long maxx_default = (long) maxx;
                // change UI onscrollview minx & maxx
                leftDate.setText("" + getDateFormat(minx_default));
                rightDate.setText("" + getDateFormat(maxx_default));
                new AsyncScroll(minx_default, maxx_default).execute();
                double getmax_weight = get_max_weight();
                double getmin_weight = get_min_weight();
                if (minx_default <= default_start_date) {
                    mRenderer.setRange(new double[] { default_start_date,
                            maxx, getmin_weight - 20, getmax_weight + 20 });

                } else {
                    mRenderer.setRange(new double[] { minx, maxx,
                            getmin_weight - 20, getmax_weight + 20 });
                }



            }
```

get_max_weights/get_min_weight get the min and maximum points from Y axis and I'm using them for rendering the graph.

It's a confusing code but I can't really post the whole code here.

Comment: Can you add what have u done ?

Comment: Edited! It's a big code so can't really post everything here.

Answer (score 4):

`setFillBelowLine` and `setFillBelowLineColor` are deprecated .

Try

```
FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ABOVE);
    fill.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    renderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill );
```

Comment: it throws indexoutofboundsException as soon as i try to pan it in a way where no points are visible.

Comment: Hey solved it.I was trying to search for min y point and max y point and trying to render the graph accordingly .so when I wasn't able to find it the graph wasn't able to render properly. just did an if else and it worked .. Thanks for the hint btw

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to search for minimum and the  maximum y data-point and rendering the graph.

So when the points go beyond the visible reason the graph was not able to render.

So here is the little code I added.

silly

```
    double minx = mRenderer.getXAxisMin();
    double maxx = mRenderer.getXAxisMax();
    double miny = mRenderer.getYAxisMin();
    double maxy = mRenderer.getYAxisMax();
    double getmax_weight = get_max_weight();
    double getmin_weight = get_min_weight();
    if (getmax_weight < 0) {
    mRenderer.setRange(new double[] { minx, maxx,miny, maxy });
    } else {
        if (minx_default <= default_start_date) {
        mRenderer.setRange(new double[] {default_start_date,                           maxx,getmin_weight - 20,
                                        getmax_weight + 20 });

                            } else {
                                mRenderer.setRange(new double[] { minx,
                                        maxx, getmin_weight - 20,
                                        getmax_weight + 20 });
                            }
                        }
                   }
```